# JSON/JQuery: How do I detect if no data is coming back from the server?

Tags: jquery, json

I have a function like this:

```
$.getJSON('<?php echo site_url('get_leads/main_contact'); ?>', 
        function(data) {
              ...
           });
```

It works fine.  But sometimes there is no data coming back from the server?  How do I detect if the JSON object is empty?  I tried "if(data == '')" and it didn't work.

Comment: What format are you expecting the data in?  An array, a series of properties, etc ...

Comment: A JSON object.  The data is json_encoded in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery.isEmptyObject

```
if (!jQuery.isEmptyObject(data)) {
    // We have data
}
```

This will at least capture an empty array, an empty object, null and undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the type of the data returned:

```
if(typeof data=="object")
    //json object returned
else if(typeof data==null)
    //nothing was returned
```